# Split an object into single-property objects

Tags: javascript

I wonder if it's possible to split an object in the following way.

Turn

```
let obj = {
    x: 3,
    y: 4,
    z: 5
}
```

into

```
[{x: 3}, {y: 4}, {z: 5}]
```

Thank you guys in advanced!

Comment: you can use this instruction `Object.entries(obj).map(elem => ( { [elem[0]] : elem[1] } ) )`

Comment: You can use use the **Object.entries()** method like this :

`let arrayOfObjects = Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => ({ [key]: value }));

console.log(arrayOfObjects); // [{x: 3}, {y: 4}, {z: 5}]`

Answer (score 1):

```js
let obj = {
    x: 3,
    y: 4,
    z: 5
}

const entries = Object.entries(obj);

const result = entries.map(([key, val]) => {
  const obj = {[key]: val}
  return obj;
});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

`Object.entries` will split into key/value tuples. Then use `map` over each to make them objects again:

```js
Object.entries({a:1, b:2, c:3}).map(x => Object.fromEntries([x]))
//=> [{a:1},{b:2},{c:3}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let obj = {
    x: 3,
    y: 4,
    z: 5
}

const result = [];

for (const k in obj) {
    result.push({[k]: obj[k]})
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will iterate over the properties/fields of the object then use a map as a new container having the key the property/field name and the value being the value of the field:

```js
Object.entries(obj).map(([key,val]) => ({ [key]: val }))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```js
let obj = {
  x: 3,
  y: 4,
  z: 5
}

let res = Object.keys(obj).map(key => {
  return {[key]: obj[key]};
})
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const result = []
for (const property in obj) {
    const myobj = {};
    myobj[`${property}`] = obj[property]
    result.push(myobj)
}
console.log(result)
```